# How do I sign a curve25519 key in golang?

Tags: algorithm, go, cryptography, ed25519, curve-25519

I am trying to implement the X3DH algorithm from Signal in Go. However, I got stuck on how to sign the Public Signed PreKey.

Per the specifications it is supposed to be an X25519 key. In looking at previous implementations on Github they generated a `[32]byte` key from the `curve25519` package and then converted it to an `ed25519` key and then signed it.

However, the packages they used for the conversion are deprecated (`github.com/agl/ed25519`). Therefore, I either need to be able to convert the keys to `ed25519` so I can sign them with the current `ed25519` package (`golang.org/x/crypto/25519`) or implement a sign and verify function for `curve25519` keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ed25519` keys can be converted to `X25519` keys easily, the twisted Edwards curve used by `Ed25519` and the Montgomery curve used by `X25519` are `birationally` equivalent.

Points on the Edwards curve are usually referred to as (`x, y`), while points on the Montgomery curve are usually referred to as (`u, v`).

You don't need a library to do the conversion, it's really simple...

```
(u, v) = ((1+y)/(1-y), sqrt(-486664)*u/x)
(x, y) = (sqrt(-486664)*u/v, (u-1)/(u+1))
```

Here is a great [blog](https://blog.filippo.io/using-ed25519-keys-for-encryption/) by Filippo Valsorda, the Golang security lead at Google, discussing this topic.

Comment: I did see that article earlier and ran into an issue. In the article it states: "It should be mentioned that there is precedent for converting keys between the two curves: Signal's XEd25519. They do the opposite of what we want to do though, they use an X25519 key for EdDSA. That comes with an issue: an X25519 public key does not carry a v coordinate, so it can map to two Ed25519 keys. They solve it by defining the Edwards point sign bit to be 0, and then negating the Edwards secret scalar if it would generate a point with positive sign." I'll be honest: I'm lost on how to implement this.

Comment: See the answer I posted below. This is what I was able to do in the end but involves using code from "golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519/internal". Again, to be honest, I'm not fully familiar with the fine details of this conversion process and greatly appreciate your input as it is not clear to me how I would put the above into code.

Comment: @Jadefox10200, so where are you at now? What part are you stuck on? It can be tricky alright...

Comment: While the below function appears to work, I dont actually totally understand what its doing. The verify function does validate the signature but since I dont understand how it's doing this I am not confident I've implemented the process correctly. Your answer did for sure help and am right now spending the time of study to actually try to understand how this works. I would prefer to implement something myself and not "rip off" code from an internal library.

Answer (score 0):

This takes in a public curve25519 key and converts it to an ed25519 public key. I did not write this code but appears to be doing what Woodstock above is stating. Further information would be welcomed:

```
func Verify(publicKey [32]byte, message []byte, signature *[64]byte) bool {

publicKey[31] &= 0x7F

/* Convert the Curve25519 public key into an Ed25519 public key.  In
particular, convert Curve25519's "montgomery" x-coordinate into an
Ed25519 "edwards" y-coordinate:
ed_y = (mont_x - 1) / (mont_x + 1)
NOTE: mont_x=-1 is converted to ed_y=0 since fe_invert is mod-exp
Then move the sign bit into the pubkey from the signature.
*/

var edY, one, montX, montXMinusOne, montXPlusOne FieldElement
FeFromBytes(&montX, &publicKey)
FeOne(&one)
FeSub(&montXMinusOne, &montX, &one)
FeAdd(&montXPlusOne, &montX, &one)
FeInvert(&montXPlusOne, &montXPlusOne)
FeMul(&edY, &montXMinusOne, &montXPlusOne)

var A_ed [32]byte
FeToBytes(&A_ed, &edY)

A_ed[31] |= signature[63] & 0x80
signature[63] &= 0x7F

var sig = make([]byte, 64)
var aed = make([]byte, 32)

copy(sig, signature[:])
copy(aed, A_ed[:])

return ed25519.Verify(aed, message, sig)
```

This uses functions from "golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519/internal"